# Change Tracking in HTML Form Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic HTML form with a handful of input elements.

They are basic stuff, no radiobuttons, checkboxes, or anything else.

The only input types are "number" and "tel" at the moment.

I need to enable/disable a save button if these values become dirty, but I'd like it to also be able to disable the save button if the user changes "12" to "13" (enable save), then reverts to "12" (disable save).

I've looked at all sorts of different answers here, different GitHub packages, etc.

Some people are saying store it all in a global dictionary, others say to use jQuery .serialize(), jQuery.Validation, data attributes, etc.

I'm currently looking into two basic GitHub packages:

https://github.com/rubentd/dirrty

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

What is the simplest way to do this given that this is a demo project with a basic form (but must be written in a way that is not specific to this form)?

**Edit**: This isn't about validation, sorry if I wasn't clear.  This is checking to see if any modifications have been made by the user.  The initial values have been added at runtime via jQuery and not in the original DOM.

Comment: "I need to enable/disable a save button if these values become dirty," What does this mean?

Comment: @RichardHamilton it means the values in the input boxes don't match some criteria, like a password needing more than 5 characters for instance.

Comment: @RichardHamilton "Dirty" ... commonly used term.   Means the user changed something.  Hence why one of the GitHub packages is called Dirrty.  And why there is MSDN documentation for SettingsPropertyValue.IsDirty.  Not matching criteria as azium said, just simply means "different".

Answer (score 2):

You can try event handling in javascript which is "onchange()".
The onchange attribute fires the moment when the value of the element is changed.

Syntax for it in HTML is :

```
<element onchange="myScript">
```

Syntax for it in Javascript is :

```
object.onchange=function(){myScript};
```

Infact for more reference you can check out the below w3school link.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

Using the above onchange event handler, now you can track your changes and process the input when the change occurs.

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://jqueryvalidation.org/ for this. This might not have the validator you are looking for, but you can specify custom validation rules using addMethod(). Examples here:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

The reverting from 13 to 12 could also be done if on this same validation method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("tel", function(value, element) {
   var valid = ... validate logic here;
   if(!valid) {
      $('#tel').val('12'); 
   }
   return valid;
}, "Please enter a correct tel!");
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I have edited the post since, this is not about validation.  I need to know if anything has been touched by the user in these input fields.  The save button should only be enabled if they changed something.

Comment: It isn't about validation but the behavior you are trying to achieve sounds very much like validation (eg. enabling/disabling submit based on form input). Checking for dirty values van be done by using $('input').change() to set some variable which can then be used with your validator. That's 'one' way of handling this. You always have the option to not use a third party jQuery plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with https://github.com/rubentd/dirrty ..

It "just works" and is very small and very simple.

```
   // Change tracking via dirrty
    $("#myForm").dirrty().on("dirty", function () {
        $("#status").html("dirty");
        $('#saveButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }).on("clean", function () {
        $("#status").html("clean");
        $('#saveButton').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

That's it.

Once anything is changed, the save button immediatly becomes avaiable.  And is disabled once the original values are restored.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Backbone model.changed() if you want to use a light framework.